# (Selenium WebDriver) Menu click pass but nothing happens on page

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

I am writing a selenium C# test code for an old "infragistics" (I seriouly don't know too much about this) page. The page doesn't give me that much options when it comes to elements references. Like in the HTML below I want to click on INVENTORY which is a submenu of a menu item but there is no element Id or Name so I used XPath (see code below). It looks like webdriver recognizes that xpath but when the click function executes and complete, nothing happens on the page. It does not open the expected page. Is there something that I am doing wrong here?

```html
<li class="igdm_MenuItemVertical igdm_MenuItemVerticalParent " unselectable="on" data-ig="x:1171509256.11:adr:1.2" adr="1.2"><A onclick="{return false;}" tabIndex=-1 class="igdm_MenuItemVerticalLink " href="#/Inventory...">
<a onclick="{return false;}" tabIndex=-1 class="igdm_MenuItemVerticalLink>
<img class="igdm_MenuItemVerticalIcon " alt="   Inventory..." src="../Images/report16.gif">
<span tabIndex=-1 unselectable="on"> INVENTORY...</span>
</a>
```

Code:

```
private By FileSubMenu = By.XPath(".//li/a/span[text()=' Inventory...']");

    public HomePage SubMenu()
    {
        int retryCount = 0;
        while (true && retryCount < Constants.RETRY_COUNT)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                IWebElement element = _driver.FindElement(FileSubMenu);
                Actions Rmouseover = new Actions(_driver);
                Rmouseover.MoveToElement(element).Click().Perform();
                return this;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (ex is WebDriverTimeoutException || ex is TimeoutException)
            {
                retryCount++;
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe because your text is uppercase `INVENTORY...` and you're looking at `text()=' Inventory...'`?

Comment: ACV, I made it uppercase here to highlight what I was trying to click. It isn't uppercase in my code. Thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: Usually with submenus, you first have to click or mouse hover on the parent menu

Comment: Yes, the mouse hover functionality for the parent menu works. And it is exactIy like the submenu I am having issues with, it doesn't have Id, Name elements. It worked with the LinkText element finder. The same functionality isn't working for the submenu for mouse hover or click

Answer (score 0):

XPath is okay, but I prefer CSS Selector as it tends to yeild less brittle selectors (not so location in the DOM based, but still can be). To get one in Chrome:

1. Right-click on the element and select 'Inspect'
2. Right-click on the element in the DOM explorer of DevTools
3. Select "Copy" > "Copy selector"

So then your code would look something like:

```
IWebElement element =  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("paste_the_selector_here"));
// Click via Selenium's Click method
element.Click();
// Or, click via JavaScript
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

Also, instead of clicking the `<span>` you may want to click on the `<a>` instead as it has an onclick event listener.

If the selector includes an ID for a parent that is dynamic, then you'll want to remove it. To remove it, find the element with that ID in the DevTool's Element tab. Double-click on the `id="..."` part and delete the whole thing. Now get the selector for the child element.

This example

```
<div id="ctl00_NavBarAdmin_WebDataMenu1"> // <- Parent div html
#ctl00_NavBarAdmin_WebDataMenu1 > ul > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li.igdm_MenuItemVertical.igdm_MenuItemVerticalParent.igdm_Me‌​nuItemVerticalSelect‌​ed > a
```

Might become

```
<div> // <- Parent div HTML
div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li.igdm_MenuItemVertical.igdm_MenuItemVerticalParent.igdm_Me‌​nuItemVerticalSelect‌​ed > a
```

Comment: Hey Timothy, I tried the steps for the CssSelector but I got: "Unable to find element with css selector...". I also tried clicking on the <a> I got "Unable to find element with css selector..."

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the DOM I will guess that a parent element has a dynamic ID attribute. If so, edit that element (in the DOM explorer) and remove the attribute entirely. Then get the selector.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that. This is the CssSeletor I copied:- #ctl00_NavBarAdmin_WebDataMenu1 > ul > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li.igdm_MenuItemVertical.igdm_MenuItemVerticalParent.igdm_MenuItemVerticalSelected > a

Comment: I will update my answer with how to remove the dynamic id.

Comment: Hi Timothy, thanks alot for you help so far and I apologies in advance if I am not following your directions correctly. I have tried the CssCelector below and I am still get "Unable to find element with css selector..."                 
                                                                                                       private By FileSubMenu = By.CssSelector("div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li.igdm_MenuItemVertical.igdm_MenuItemVerticalParent.igdm_Me‌​nuItemVerticalSelect‌​ed > a ");

Comment: Also I will like to add, the mouse hover functionality for the parent menu works. And it is exactIy like the submenu I am having issues with, it doesn't have Id, Name elements. It worked with the LinkText element finder. The same functionality isn't working for the submenu for mouse hover or click

Comment: It looks like your selector is also using the element's class. `li.igdm_MenuItemVertical.igdm_MenuItemVerticalParent.igdm_Me‌​‌​nuItemVerticalSele‌​ct‌​ed` is actually a `<li>` where `class=idm...` You can remove this class like you did with the ID or replace that part of your selector with `li` or `li:nth-child(1)` (assuming it is the first li in the ul). I have a similar problem with KendoUI where once I click something the classes change.

Comment: Timothy, now webdriver is able to find the css selector,  but now I am back to the original issue: nothing happens on the page. It does not open the expected page. Very frustrating haha

Comment: I have changed the way I am performing the click, by using JavaScript, now I am getting new error: "Argument is of an illegal typeBy.CssSelector: div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a ']"

Comment: The `<a>` has the `onclick` event which should be triggered by the .Click(). If at all possible I would get with your Dev to make sure that is what should happen (there might be other conditions that need to be met first). Once, I had a form submit button that wouldn't be enabled unless I triggered the blur() event on the inputs first.